# Which takes less Cpu/memory/ram... etc?

Tags: c#, resources, cpu

I have some coding-resource realted questions :

> Q1 :

**A:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{

FunA(i);
FunB(i);

}
```

Or

**B:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{

FunA(i);

}

for (int i = 0; i < 15 ; i++)
{

FunB(i);

}
```

does B take more resources than A because there are 2 loops ? *and why ?*

> Q2:

**A:**

```
FunA(10*2-15+15/X);
FunA(10*2-15+15/X);
FunA(10*2-15+15/X);
```

**B:**

```
int result=10*2-15+15/X;
    FunA(result);
    FunA(result);
    FunA(result);
```

does A take more resource because it have to calculate result every time or B takes more ? does compiler understand results are same and make a variable out of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use a profiler.**

For your second question the C# compiler is going to optimize compile-time constants such as `10*2-15+15`.

Your second `B` example is better code despite the compiler potentially optimizing the `A` example for you.

Performance aside, the second `A` example is just bad coding practices.  Unnecessary duplicate constants (more chance for user error, especially if you change this code later on).

That said, a good rule of thumb is don't rely on compiler optimizations.  Try and make the code readable and for things that actually *are* constant you should literally *define* them as `const`:

```
const int WHATEVER = 10 * 2 - 15 + 15;
int result = WHATEVER / X;
FunA(result);
FunA(result);
FunA(result);
```

Finally, here's the obligatory mention that profiling is almost always more accurate than rolling your own benchmarks (which I see written incorrectly more times than not).  Visual Studio 2017 has a built-in profiler or you can use a variety of other ones out there.

When in doubt about performance, don't guess.  Get actual metrics.

Comment: i wanted to know about the compiler optimization thanks